# setting the height of a div to images with no height inside the div

Tags: css

I need some help please. I want the images with class "banner" to stretch proportionally with the width of the browser window. How do I get the height of the div with class "bannerBox" to adapt to the variable height of the images with class "banner" and how do I get the div with class "container" to position itself under the banner images?

The image with class "banner" is supposed to be an image rotator with many images that cross fade. I took the other images and the javascript out to simplify my code so it's easy to understand.

Thank you.

This is the stylesheet:

```
.bannerBox
    {
    background:#f0f;
    min-height:100px;
    width:100%;
    }

.banner
    {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    }

.container
    {
    background:#ff0;
    width:1000px;
    height:20px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:50px 0px 50px 0px;
    }
```

and this is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div class="bannerBox">
                <img class="banner" id="banner1" src="http://hascob.com/banner1.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <p>Hello!</p>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your banner class has absolute positioning. This causes the image to be positioned relative to the browser window. Removing this will add it back into the flow of the page

```
position:absolute;
```

That is causing all of your problems.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzekhz0j/)

Comment: The position "absolute" is necessary as this is an image rotator. without the position "absolute" the image that fades in appears under the image that fades out. When the image that fades out disappears, the image that faded in then jumps up to take the place where the image was that faded out.

Comment: Then this isn't a css or html issue, it is a javascript issue. The javascript needs to finish the transition and remove the element from the DOM before it adds in a new element.

Comment: But two images are displayed during the cross fading from one image to another. Without positioning, the images are displayed as two different images, just as they would appear in the flow of the html code.

Comment: I see.... With absolute positioning, the banner is not considered to be inside of the bannerBox, so the height is not going to adjust automatically. You will need to write javascript to handle this part of the transition as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answers LeBarton, but I still do not see how any div could be positioned under the banner, in the flow, if there is no height set for the image. I will try to have javascript detect the width of the browser window with an window.onresize event and then set the width and height of the image and the position of the next following div. I have a hard time believing there is no easier CSS solution to this problem though. Isn't there a CSS styling to apply to bannerBox so that the images are "inside" the bannerBox?